# Ajax Push Engine (APE): How to Send Binary Data or Special Characters

Tags: ajax, json, post, binary-data, ape

This code example is from the APE official website: http://www.ape-project.org/

```
var client = new APE.Client();

client.load();

client.core.join('testChannel');

client.request.send('foo', {ping: 'ho hey', fieldWidthBinaryDataOrSpecialCharacters: '+/'});

client.onRaw('bar', function(raw, pipe) {
    console.log('echo : ' + raw.data.echo);
    console.log('Receiving : ' + raw.data.hello);
});
```

When I receive the data at the server side, I found that the special characters `+/` has been URL encoded (`%2B%2F`).

Is APE always using GET?  If we use POST, I think we can post any data including Binary data, right?  But how to use POST in JSON?

My case is, even I don't use the Binary format, I have to use the Base64.  But the standard Base64 uses `+/` which is not URL safe.  You might suggest using the URL safe version of Base64, but URLSafeBase64 is not standard and it might also create other problems.

Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did two-step encoding:

The Client Side:

1. Base64 Encoding;

Server Side:

1. URL Decoding; (It seems the URL encoding is automatically done somewhere in the APE)
2. Base64 Decoding.

P.S.: If any one knows how to do it in a more efficient way of transferring binary data, please let me know, and I will re-mark your answer as the correct one.